# distance between a real and R\Q

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Please how to prove that $d(x, R\setminus Q)=0, d(x,Q)=0$ for all $x\in 
\mathbb{R}$ ?

I know that $d(x,R\setminus Q)=\inf_{a\in R\setminus Q} d(x, a)$ but how to continue ?

Can i say that As $\overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ and $d(x, \overline{A})=d(x,A)$ then $d(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})=d(x,\mathbb{R}) =0$

Thank you

Comment: What space do you consider? On the one hand you have $Q$ and $R \setminus Q$ then you have for all $x\in 
\mathbb{R}^N$. This does not fit together.

Comment: @quid it is R not R^N sorry

Comment: Have you heard of a set being "dense" in the reals?

Comment: On your edit: yes, if you know that, you could argue like this, otherwise it is a circular. Whether or not this is the case, is impossible to tell.

Comment: @quid i don't understand the last part

Comment: I cannot know what results you know already and thus are entitled to use in resolving this problem.

Comment: @quid my edit is right ?

Comment: It is right if you know the results you invoke.

Comment: @Vrouvrou if one of the answers addresses your concerns you should consider accepting it. If not, you might want to consider commenting with why you are unsatisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R-Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus for all $x\in\mathbb{R},\epsilon>0$, there exists an $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and a $b\in\mathbb{R-Q}$ such that $d(x,a)<\epsilon$ and $d(x,b)<\epsilon$. The result follows.

Comment: can i say: $d(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})=d(x,\mathbb{R}) =0$ because $\overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, that works, and my argument is basically the same as that

Answer (score 1):

To show that $d (x, \mathbb{Q})=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ what you need to show is that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a rational number such that $|x-y|< \epsilon$. I assume you are aware of the fact that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. This is basically the same thing.

To show that $d (x, \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ what you need to show is that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an irrational number such that $|x-y|< \epsilon$.
This is more or less the same as above, but I might set up the proof differently. For $x$ is irrational the assertion is clear (take $x=y$), and 
for rational $x$ consider $x + \sqrt{2}/n$ for growing integral $n$ (or take whatever irrational instead of $\sqrt{2}$).